# Миграция с Drupal на Drupal

Tags: drupal, миграция

Необходимо перенести контент, таксономию в связке с нодами, на новый сайт *Drupal* со старого сайта *Drupal*, сохраняя при этом *url* адреса, таковыми, какими они были на старом сайте. Пробовал модуль *Features*, он действительно переносит, но ссылки при этом прописывает новые, а необходимо сохранить ссылки как есть на старом сайте, то есть например если на старом сайте `node/60`, то нужно что бы и на новом после восстановления было у этой же ноды `node/60`.  Подскажите как можно это исправить.

И какие модули вообще лучше подойдут для переноса контента с Drupal на Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Перенести `id` нод вряд ли получится, так-как *Drupal* создает ноды заново и по порядку. На старом сайте были уделенные ноды, соответственно он эти `id` пропускает.

Переносить лучше как описано [здесь](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), а дальше я думаю возможны два варианта:

1. брать `url` "старых" нод и вставлять как синоним для "новых"
2. добавить на новом сайте поле, в которое вставлять значение `id`
   старых нод и на основании этого поля уже генерировать шаблон `url`.

Answer (score 0):

А [Backup & Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) не пробовали?
Этот модуль создает копию sql-базы. Возможно, он сохранит нужные Вам id.

Либо другой вариант -- через PHPMyAdmin сделать экспорт базы. А на новом сайте -- импорт. (Но это если есть доступ к базам).

Answer (score 0):

После миграции можно перезаписать id node. 
Для этого нужен скрипт который будет подключаться к двум БД старой и новой и к примеру брать содержимое страницы в новой бд, искать по этому содержимому в старой  id  и перезаписывать в новой БД корректный id /  Карусель в общем но действенная.
Главное верно настроть Базу данных чтобы она пропускала дубликаты id node.
А после завершения карусели необходимо будет проверить не остались ли дубликаты id  в новой БД.
И вернуть настройки поля id по завершении чтобы дубликаты снова были невозможны.